# How to implement a base form in multiple views in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

So I have a `base.html` file where all the components that are common in all the other templates are present. I'm trying to implement Newsletter form functionality in my django project. This form should be displayed on all the pages(in the top navbar).
But the problem here is that this form only shows up on `base.html` and not the other template pages which extend this file.

`base.html`

```html
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div class="overlay-body form-group">
      <h2>Subscribe to our newsletter</h2>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="reset" onclick="off()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <header>
      <div>
        <div class="col-4 "><a id="blog-side" onclick="on()">Subscribe</a></div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
          <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo"> 
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="title">Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 "><a href="{% url 'about' %}" id="blog-side">About</a></div>
      </div>
    </header>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Newsletter form from `models.py`

```py
class Newsletter(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  entered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

`forms.py`

```py
class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Newsletter
    fields = ('email', )
```

Any idea as to how to setup this form in the other templates?

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that you will need to make sure you send in the form in every single view you create. Can I see your `views.py` file please?